# Modifying default templates for FormView

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, t4

I use the FormView control quite a bit, but I wish I had more control over the default templates.

When I drag a FormView from the toolbox onto my page and point it to a DataSource control it prepopulates the ItemTemplate, EditItemTemplate and InsertItemTemplates, but it doesn't do it very well.

For example, the InsertItemTemplate looks like this by default:

```
<InsertItemTemplate>
id:
<asp:TextBox ID="IDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id") %>' />
<br />
Name:
<asp:TextBox ID="NameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' />
...
</InsertItemTemplate>
```

But what I would prefer is a good old fashioned html table

```
<InsertItemTemplate>
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>
     id:
   </td>
   <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="IDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id") %>' />
    </td>
  <tr>
  ...
</table>
</insertItemTemplate>
```

I know I can use a DetailsView to get a table rendered out, but I end up modifying the form so much that I prefer to use the FormView. It's just that I would like Visual Studio to start me out a bit closer to where I want to end up.

I would imagine that there is a T4 template somewhere in the guts of VS that I might be able to modify to get this done.

Anybody had any luck with this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0):

Wow interesting question, but I don't think it is modifiable or a T4 template; I personally think its in the FormView's control designer that the control implements.  These types of design-time settings can be present there.  Unfortunately, a lot of the features within the design-time framework aren't customizable like that, unless you have a third-party plugin.

However, you may be able to achieve what you are looking to do through a snippet, as depicted here: http://vbcity.com/blogs/mike-mcintyre/archive/2009/02/03/visual-studio-2010-net-4-0-snippets-in-aspx-page-markup.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you click the control itself within visual editor of visual studio, there is a little arrow, click that and there is an option there to stop using the default template.

Sorry to be vague, but I don't have Visual Studio on my home PC